# How to access certain mailitem properties/methods in a Visual Studio Outlook Add-In?

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2013, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook (2010) add-in using Visual Studio 2013 (Targeting .NET 4).

Certain Outlook properties/methods seem to be unavailable.

The following code works from Outlook VBA.

```vb
Public Sub OutlookTest()

    'Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application  (NOT NEEDED FOR OUTLOOK VBA)
    Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection   ' You need a selection object for getting the selection.
    Dim oItem As Object             ' You don't know the type yet.    
        
    Set oExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 'Get the ActiveExplorer.
    Set oSel = oExp.Selection           ' Get the selection.

    For i = 1 To oSel.Count         ' Loop through all the currently .selected items
        Set oItem = oSel.Item(i)        ' Get a selected item.
        Call DisplayInfo(oItem)          ' Display information about it.
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayInfo(oItem As Object)

    Dim strMessageClass As String
    Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    ' You need the message class to determine the type.
    strMessageClass = oItem.MessageClass

    If (strMessageClass = "IPM.Note") Then          ' Mail Entry.
        Set oMailItem = oItem
        MsgBox oMailItem.Subject
        MsgBox oMailItem.EntryID
        MsgBox oMailItem.HTMLBody
        oMailItem.SaveAs "C:\Users\u001tb7\Desktop\New folder\testOL.msg", olMSG
    Else
            MsgBox "Pick something else"
        End If

    End Sub
```

When I try near identical code from Visual Studio in an add-in:

```vb
Private Sub butSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles butSettings.Click

    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection   ' You need a selection object for getting the selection.
    Dim oItem As Object             ' You don't know the type yet.

    oExp = oApp.ActiveExplorer      ' Get the ActiveExplorer.
    oSel = oExp.Selection           ' Get the selection.

    For i = 1 To oSel.Count         ' Loop through all the currently .selected items
        oItem = oSel.Item(i)        ' Get a selected item.
        DisplayInfo(oItem)          ' Display information about it.
    Next i

End Sub

Sub DisplayInfo(oItem As Object)

    Dim strMessageClass As String
    Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    ' You need the message class to determine the type.
    strMessageClass = oItem.MessageClass

    If (strMessageClass = "IPM.Note") Then          ' Mail Entry.
        oMailItem = oItem
        MsgBox(oMailItem.Subject)
        MsgBox(oMailItem.EntryID)
        MsgBox(oMailItem.HTMLBody)      '<---FAILS
        oMailItem.SaveAs("C:\Users\u001tb7\Desktop\New folder\testVS.msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG)  '<---ALSO FAILS
    Else
        MsgBox("Pick something else")
    End If

End Sub
```

I get an error on `MailItem.HTMLBody` and `MailItem.SaveAs` but NOT `MailItem.Subject` or `.EntryID`.

This makes me suspect it's something to do with the security, as I think properties like `.HTMLBody` are 'protected', but `.EntryID` and `.Subject` are not.

The error is the generic COM exception not giving me any detail:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in MsgSave.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Is there any way to get Outlook to 'trust' my VS code (for eventual distribution)?  Or is there something else amiss?

EDIT: Thanks to both below!

Instead of:

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
```

Use:

```
Dim oApp as Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> certain outlook properties/methods seem to be unavailable

What properties are you talking about? Could you be more specific?

As Dmitry suggested, you need to use the Application property provided by VSTO. In that case you will avoid security prompts or exceptions. Typically you get such issue when you try to automate Outlook from a standalone application. The Application object provided by VSTO is trusted and doesn't generate exceptions for secured properties or methods (for example, MailItem.Send). You can read more about that in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) article.

Comment: Properties like are mentioned in the article you posted.  E.g. MailItem.To (or .Body).  That article is what led me to believe it was a security issue.  I the Dmitry is on the right track that I don't need to declare a new Outlook instance, but now I'm just struggling to figure out how to access the 'free' Outlook instance from classes other than "ThisAddIn"

Comment: You need to use the instance provided by the Application property.

Comment: So I would think to do this I would do:

`Dim oApp as Outlook.Application
oExplorer = oApp.ActiveExploreer`

Then intellisense is showing me the expected properties like .ActiveExplorer, but it's warning me that oApp hasn't been defined yet, and throws a nullreference exception at runtime.

Comment: It looks like you didn;t initialize it in the code.     Dim oApp as Outlook.Application  = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

Answer (score 2):

Do not use  `New Outlook.Application` in an Outlook addin - you get Outlook.Application object for free when your addin starts up.

Comment: That makes sense.  But how can I access the application property from places other than the 'ThisAddIn' Class?  For example  the original code I posted resides under a Ribbon class.  I can get 'Outlook.Application', but then there's no Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.

I tried making a a Public Function under 'ThisAddIn' that make the Outlook.Application object available to other classes, but that function wasn't accessible to other the other classes.

(I hope I'm not mixing terminology - I'm self taught and sometimes things don't mean what I think they mean).  Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Visual Studio 2013, with Visual Studio Tools for Office 2013 Update 1.

Comment: Use Globals.ThisAddIn.Application